# How to print a particular DIV with external CSS included in PHP and Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need to print a particular div with styles included by clicking the button in wordpress using php. I tried the below things, but the CSS is not included. Can anyone help me out?

```js
function printDiv(DivName){
    var printContents = document.getElementById(DivName).innerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
      myWindow.document.write('<Link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css />')
      myWindow.document.write('<html><body>'+printContents+'</body></html>');
      
      myWindow.print();
      myWindow.close();

      return true;
}
```

Comment: In general, that is a valid approach, did you check your browser's Developers Tools for errors? Are you sure that CSS path is correct, and there are no other errors from JS or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. you need to use `media="print"`.

https://jsfiddle.net/qtyzowjm/3/

```
function printDiv(DivName){
    var printContents = document.getElementById(DivName).innerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
      myWindow.document.write('<Link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css media="print"/>')
      myWindow.document.write('<html><body>'+printContents+'</body></html>');
      
      myWindow.print();
      
}
```

Comment: My CSS is not getting included in the print window

Comment: can you share your html and CSS or create a fiddle?

Comment: here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qtyzowjm/3/